# HTML entities being displayed as raw html

Tags: html

I am very confused why my html tags are getting converted into html entities. I checked in my database and it is non-encoded HTML, but when I load the page it shows raw html code.

I am trying to embed youtube videos but when I paste and submit the form it stores non-encoded html in database, but when i load that page in browser it shows raw html code.

What it should be:

```
<object width="640" height="385">
 <param name="movie" value=" name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
 <embed src=" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed>
</object>
```

When I see in firebug it shows:

```
&lt;object width="640" height="385"&gt;
 &lt;param name="movie" value=" name="allowFullScreen" value="true"&gt;&lt;/param&gt;
 &lt;param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"&gt;&lt;/param&gt;
 &lt;embed src=" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"&gt;&lt;/embed&gt;
&lt;/object&gt;
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Show us how you are storing and retrieving the data from the database.

Comment: The HTML is encoded by the server. What server side technology are you using? Show us the server side code (the code that gets the value from DB).

Comment: Steeve - It's hard to answer without you providing more specifics. What are you using to transfer entries from your database to your webpage, e.g. php, jQuery/JSON?

Comment: @frankie the data is stored as text

Comment: @ken yes i am using php and jquery. and its standard php code to retrive data

Comment: This isn't a good solution but until you find a better one, you can try [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.html-entity-decode.php)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember having this issue a while back, I believe it might be related to the type of info in the DB you have it set as. LongText or ASCII or something like that. Have you tried changing that?

Comment: These types of comments should not be added as answers; please use the comment functionality below the question. `:)`

Comment: what type it should be for displaying html. i am using text